# Problems uploading repository to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to upload a git repository created on my desktop to Github via the terminal. These are the steps I've taken

```
git init [directory]  
git add [files]  
git remote add origin [remote repository URL]  
git remote -v   
git commit -m "changes"  
git push origin master
```

The response:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create the remote repository? Or just make up a URL? What happens when you put the URL in a browser?

Comment: can you fetch the remote? try `git fetch origin` to make sure thr url points somewhere ok

Comment: @AaronBrager When it comes to creating a remote repository, it asks for a URL which I make up. When I load the URL a 404 message appears.

Comment: @OznOg when I do fetch, it says the respository is not found.

Comment: I am told that I must create a repository on Github first. Is this correct? Is it not possible to upload a file that you create on your desktop via terminal? If I use Github desktop it works.

Comment: Github desktop "knows" how to create a repository on the server based on your log-in credentials. The git command line tools know nothing of this. So yes, you need to create your repository on the server and set the origin for that repository to your local one before you can push.

Comment: @crashmstr Thanks for the help. I literally thought it would be possible to upload a repository to Github using the command line.

Comment: @szewah It *is* possible, but you do have the step (hidden by Github Desktop) of creating the repository on the server. Once you have done that, I believe Github shows you the steps to upload any code you might already have locally (basically the same steps you have, but with the *specific* repository URL that was created).

Comment: If you want to create GitHub repos from the command line you can install the `hub` Command